# Each column has at most $s$ zeros, the matrix has rank $\leq s+1$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Each column has at most $s$ zeros, the $n\times n$ matrix has rank $\leq s+1$?

Is this true? Can we prove this by induction on $n$ or $r$?

Comment: The identity matrix is a counterexample.

Comment: Please consider that it may be a bit rude to radically change the problem after it's already been answered.

Comment: Generate a random large matrix with a random real entry from $[-1,1]$. It is almost certain that each column has no zeros, and it is almost certain that the matrix is of full rank.

Comment: @user i am sorry for this. I may post another problem in later convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the revised post. Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. To make the matrix $A$, add $2$ to every entry of $I$. The matrix $A$ has full rank.  For its determinant is congruent to $1$ modulo $2$.

The matrix $A$ has at most $0$ zeros in each column. Thus $A$ has rank $\gt s+1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: The matrix $A$ has full rank?

Comment: @xldd: It does. But I changed it a little to make the fact of full rank trivial.

Comment: I have no idea on your idea.

Comment: We show that the $n\times n$ matrix with $3$'s down the main diagonal and $2$'s elsewhere is of full rank (invertible). Imagine finding the determinant in the usual way. The determinant will be odd, and therefore non-zero.